# Under what conditions $c = \gamma(\alpha(c))$ for a Galois connection?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, monotone-functions, galois-connections

I have the basic definition of Galois connection.

> Let $(C,\leq)$ and $(A,\sqsubseteq)$ be partial orders and $\alpha: C
>  \rightarrow A$, $\gamma: A \rightarrow C$ monotonic functions. They
>   form a Galois connection if $\forall c,a. \alpha(c) \sqsubseteq a \iff
>  c \leq \gamma(a)$ (*).

Then I was able to proof some properties on them:

> 1. The condition (*) is equivalent to $\forall c,a. c \leq \gamma(\alpha(c)) \land \alpha(\gamma(a)) \sqsubseteq a$ (**).
> 2. Given a Galois connection the following are equivalent:
>      2.1 $\alpha(\gamma(a)) = a \; \forall a \in A$.
>      2.2 $\alpha$ is a surjective function.
>      2.3 $\gamma$ is an injective function.

Now I have to proof the following more imprecise statement:

> When does $c = \gamma(\alpha(c)) \; \forall c$ hold? Assuming that $C$
>   is the set of concrete states and $A$ is the domain of static
>   analysis, what is more likely $c = \gamma(\alpha(c)) \; \forall c$ or
>   $\alpha(\gamma(a)) = a \; \forall a \in A$.

So I need to give a necessary and sufficient condition for $c = \gamma(\alpha(c)) \; \forall c$ to hold.  Any other intuition you may have is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will have $c=\gamma(\alpha(c))$ if and only if $c$ is in the range of $\gamma$.

If $\gamma\circ\alpha$ and $\alpha\circ\gamma$ are both identities, then - by definition - $(C,\le)$ and $(A,\sqsubseteq)$ are isomorphic.

In general, $T:=\gamma\circ\alpha$ will be a *closure operator*, i.e. idempotent  ($T\circ T=T$), increasing, and preserving arbitrary meets.